# How to find pairs of slightly differing file names with similar core names using python

Tags: python, filenames, glob

I have a list of files with similar basenames, some of which are slightly differing. 
Atwood_1_F , 
Atwood_1_B , 
Atwood_1_F2 , 
Atwood_1_B2

I need to find a way to create a list of paired values. The basename in the above list are Atwood_1 and Atwood_2. In this specific list, I would need to create 2 sets of  pairs with the same baseline:
Pair1: should contain Atwood_1_**F** & Atwood_1_**B**
Pair2: should contain Atwood_1_**F2** & Atwood_1_**B2**

This is a small subset of several needed pairs. Does anyone have any ideas of ways to create these pairs in python?

Comment: It completely depends on what your criteria for a pair is

Answer (score -1):

So if I am understanding you correctly, you need to end up with 2 lists? Or is it you need 2 variables containing the files? In either case the method startswith() should start you out. Just call it on your lists (or otherwise), and set what you want the string to start with. Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you should be able to use the method as such:

```
    if str.startswith("Atwood_1_F", beg=0,end=len(string)-1);
    elif str.startswith("Atwood_1_B", beg=0,end=len(string)-1); //the -1 in both statments only serve to denote the F from F2 as len(string)-1 on F will be "_" but the same from F2 will be "F"
    Pair1.append(str)
```

You just need to then similarly append Pair2, and that should answer your question, if I understood it. Let me know if I helped.